# Issue Moq'ing HttpResponseMessage

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq

I have the following Method:

```
public async Task<SecurityRoleDeleteResult> DeleteSecurityRoleByRoleId(int securityRoleId)
{
    string url = $"{_housingDataSecurityConfiguration.HousingDataSecurityWebApiUrl}SecurityRoles/Delete";

    HttpResponseMessage message = _apiClientService.Post(url, securityRoleId);

    if (message.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
    {
        return SecurityRoleDeleteResult.ErrorOccurred;
    }

    int intResult = 0;
    var apiResult = await message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    if (int.TryParse(apiResult, out intResult))
    {
        return (SecurityRoleDeleteResult)intResult;
    }
    else
    {
        return SecurityRoleDeleteResult.ErrorOccurred;
    }
}
```

I'm now trying to write a unit test for it and so far have:

```
[Test]
public async Task DeleteSecurityRoleByRoleId()
{
    _mockApiClientService.Setup(a => a.Post(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<int>()))
        .Returns(new HttpResponseMessage {StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK});

    SecurityRoleDeleteResult result = await _securityRoleService.DeleteSecurityRoleByRoleId(It.IsAny<int>());

    Assert.AreEqual(SecurityRoleDeleteResult.Success, result);
}
```

The issue here is that when running the test in the `_securityRoleService.DeleteSecurityRoleByRoleId` method at the point I try to set `var apiResult` message.content is null, because in this instance I'm only mocking so crashes.

How can I mock this out so that my test will work?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I figured out my issue. Rather than delete my question, I thought I'd post my change to the test. Basically I hadn't mocked the content.

```
HttpContent content = new StringContent("4");

_mockApiClientService.Setup(a => a.Post(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<int>()))
    .Returns(new HttpResponseMessage { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK, Content = content });
```

So depending on the content type you may want to have returned you may need to change the type of content.